# How Delphi DataSnap (XE) TClientDataSet/TDataSetProvider handlers network communication issues (lost packets, lags, etc.)?

Tags: delphi, networking, datasnap, tclientdataset

I have Delphi (XE) DataSnap application (Firebird/IBX) that entire object graph saves in several separate TclientDataSets: InvoiceCDS, InvoiceLineCDS, GoodCDS. When the user saves data, then DataSnap client application calls:

```
if InvoiceCDS.ChangeCount > 0 then InvoiceCDS.ApplyUpdates(0); 
if GoodCDS.ChangeCount > 0 then GoodCDS.ApplyUpdates(0); 
if InvoiceLineCDS.ChangeCount > 0 then InvoiceLineCDS.ApplyUpdates(0);
```

There are 3 (or more) sets of TDataSetProvider, TIBQuery, TIBUpdateSQL on the TDSServerModule of the DataSnap server application, so – each of the client CDS communicates with its respective DSP/Query/Update on the server form. Each TDataSetProvider has AfterApplyUpdates code:

```
SomeQry.Transaction.CommitRetaining;
```

And each TDataSetProvider also has OnUpdateError code:

```
WriteErrorMessageInLog(E.Message)
```

As I understand, then such OnUpdateError code effectively just records the bad update call and skips bad records and saves the records that can be saved in database without database (Firebird) errors.

All the IBQueries ar attached to the same transaction and so – each ApplyUpdates call on the client side is executed in one retained transaction on the server side.

This is the architecture of our application – with intention to save as much data as is possible. But we experience some very strange errors only in cases when client and server is separated by low quality network (with packet loss and time lags). We are thinking that there can be some records that are not updates and that are keeping their old values. But there are no error messages in the server log (i.e. there are no OnUpdateError calls). We have checked that OnUpdateError is called in case of Firebird errors, so, we have no Firebird errors. But data are not saved still.

**So – how DataSnap handles lost packets and similar network level errors?** **Are there events that can process network level problems?** As I understand from http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Applying_Updates then **there is no chance for network errors to disturb normal flow of application** – entire Delta packet of ClientDataSet is sent to the server (and I guess, if DataSnap does not receive well formated Delta then it silently repeats the call – that can explain the slow performance of application then network packet loss is artificially introducted on the localhost with Clumsy https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/ ) and server then applied this delta to database. I guess **there is no chance that some of the records from the Delta can be sent to the server but some of the records from the Delta are getting lost during network communication, isn’t it so?** So, where the strange errors about lost updates can arise?